# Change Date format (yyyy-mm-dd) to (yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss) in Oracle db at the time of retrieval

Tags: spring-mvc, oracle11g

I found a strange behaviour in spring mvc where i am saving a date of birth as in DATE format also its get write in oracle db as in same format but at the time of retrieval it's getting converted to dateTimeStamp format.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

```
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);

    // Format date into output format
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String outputString = outputFormat.format(date);
```